# How parser String to date formate

Tags: java, android, date-format

I have doubts about how parser a String (EditText) for an Date formate
I need sent to my DataBase in this format: 1991-04-01 00:00:00

But my code return in this format: Thur Apr 11 00:00:00 BTR 1991

Can you please help me in parse my EditText to Date in this format: 1991-04-01 00:00:00

follow my code:

```
Date newFormat = new Date();
String birthday = (mEditTextBirthday.getText().toString());
try {
      newFormat = format.parse(birthday+" 00:00:00");
     } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            mUser.setBirthday(newFormat);
```

Comment: What is `format` here? Did you try googling? There must be hundreds of questions and answers describing how to parse and format dates in java.

Comment: yes, but in this example I cannot find any question about this.

Comment: in stacker show all format, but I cannot find format YYYY MM DD HH:MM:SS when I send this format DDMMYYYY

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
String birthday = mEditTextBirthday.getText();
Date = new Date();
try {
    date = format.parse(birthday + " 00:00:00");
} [...]
```

Looks like you are using a wrongly defined SimpleDateFormat.

[JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) provides you with many examples.